# VSCode: Is it possible to differentiate foregroundColor for staged (add) and staged (edit)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Both staged: added and edited files respond to the **gitDecoration.modifiedResourceForeground**

Before opening feature request I was wondering if there is a way to differentiate those files inside the FileExplorer

Thanks

Comment: Take a look here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_git-colors . I don't know if there is a settings for those statuses

Comment: yes I did, and tried all the options, but none of them differentiate modifiedResourceForeground from a "added" file. Thanks for the response though